# How do I reduce the space between column-pairs of the following equations

Tags: align, amsmath

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book} 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{h}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    78 \\
    60
\end{bmatrix} & \mathbf{y}_{2}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}       \\
\mathbf{Z}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}& \mathbf{U}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

I have tried using the command `\renewcommand\minalignsep{0pt}` but nothing is changing.

Comment: Are you using  one of the standard classes?

Comment: Standard classes...? You mean?

Comment: article, or report, &c.

Comment: Im using the following class, \documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}

Comment: OK, so there's no problem with my suggestion. In the posted code, just replace `article`  with your class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have control on the spacing between alignment columns, use the `alignat` environment. The following code uses a spacing of 2em:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mathbf{h}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    78 \\
    60
\end{bmatrix} &\qquad \mathbf{y}_{2}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix} \\
\mathbf{Z}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}& \mathbf{U}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Bernard. It worked perfectly.